# Duplicate style.css in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, styles, loading

I have a link to a style.css with version, which is updating each time after changing the file in my theme on server:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css?v=1477025590" />
```

Also, I can see another link to the same style.css in the source of code but with an old version which doesn't change automatically (it's a standart link of a theme):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-style-css'  href='example.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Is it normal? User should load a file twice or I can delete the second link somehow via functions.php?

Comment: Yes you need to check in your functions.php is there this css load twice ? you can find wp_enque_style function over there

Comment: Thank you! Found this line in functions.php

Comment: Welcome keep helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes you need to check in your functions.php is there this css load
>   twice ? you can find wp_enque_style function over there.

**Remove the css from there which loads twice it will solve your error**

Comment: it's wp_enqueue_style not wp_enque_style ;)